# How to create multiple folders from various data in various sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I used to be running only one formula, now I tried running both formulas and couldn't get it to run.

I tried doing everything in one formula, but got a mistake in vr2

```html
function foldersunidos(){
  function createAndHyperlink();
  function createAndHyperlink2()}
  
function createAndHyperlink() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var parent=DriveApp.getFolderById("1Jr39EIlYZ2P4j22OWjP7b_k7gupelXDy")
  var vr=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);//column 1 is values
  var v=vr.getValues();
  var dr=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow(),1);//column 2 is hyperlinks
  var d=dr.getValues();
  var hr=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1);//column 3 is done ... Prevent old assignment from getting recreated
  var h=hr.getFormulas();
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
    if(v[i][0] && !h[i][0] && !d[i][0]) {
      var folder=parent.createFolder(v[i][0]);
      var formula='=HYPERLINK("' + folder.getUrl() + '"; "' + v[i][0] + '")';
      h[i][0]=formula;
      d[i][0]='Done';
    }
  }
  dr.setValues(d);
  hr.setFormulas(h)
}

function createAndHyperlink2() {
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh2=ss2.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var parent2=DriveApp.getFolderById("1JA80Cjt9WQv-WW8wlZpyVZPVSJ9CD1yK")
  var vr2=sh2.getRange(1,1,sh2.getLastRow(),1);//column 1 is values
  var v2=vr2.getValues();
  var dr2=sh2.getRange(1,3,sh2.getLastRow(),1);//column 2 is hyperlinks
  var d2=dr2.getValues();
  var hr2=sh2.getRange(1,2,sh2.getLastRow(),1);//column 3 is done ... Prevent old assignment from getting recreated
  var h2=hr2.getFormulas();
  for(var i=0;i<v2.length;i++) {
    if(v2[i][0] && !h2[i][0] && !d2[i][0]) {
      var folder2=parent2.createFolder(v2[i][0]);
      var formula2='=HYPERLINK("' + folder2.getUrl() + '"; "' + v2[i][0] + '")';
      h2[i][0]=formula2;
      d2[i][0]='Done';
    }
  }
  dr2.setValues(d2);
  hr2.setFormulas(h2)
}
```

Should get two values strings of folders in two different sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function foldersunidos(){
  createAndHyperlink();
  createAndHyperlink2();
}
```

And add `return` to each of the "createAndHyperlink" functions:

```
...
  dr.setValues(d);
  hr.setFormulas(h);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Yes ADW, that is exactly it! Thank you